# Can't import project to android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to use [this](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser) library

I've added

```
compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.0@aar'
```

to dependecies.

My top level build file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And it gives me error "failed to refresh gradle project" with reference to the project, that I'm trying to import.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This library is not on Central Maven as aar.

Check here:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cnet.rdrei.android.dirchooser
it is an apklib format.

I've checked the snapshots repo, and here you can find this library.

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/net/rdrei/android/dirchooser/library/

To use the snap repo you have to change your script:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
    }
}
```

Then add you depencency, for example

```
compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

Comment: Which gradle wrapper version are you using? Check also you gradle console.

Comment: Well, I don't know... I've tried to download gradle from ubuntu repositories and it's still not working.

Comment: check the value of distributionUrl inside gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties inside your project.

Comment: http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip

Comment: There should be an AAR for relaseses and snapshots.

http://maven-repository.com/artifact/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser/library/2.0

I'm personally using `compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.0@aar'`

Comment: Update: Looks like compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.2-SNAPSHOT' now

Comment: This saves my day. Thank you.. :D

Comment: It is also worth to be noticed that, the repositories list which should be updated is the one for `allproject` or specific module, not for `buildscript`.

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by @unify @GabrieleMariotti and @AndyJoiner is correct. However it confused be since we have two gradle files - a **project level gradle** and a **inner gradle** (where you write your dependencies). The solution is to add the code suggested by @AndyJoiner inside your **inner gradle**.

Since I was confused as to where to add the code, which took me an hour to figure out, I don't want it to happen to others. So, I am posting my both gradle files.

**Project Level Gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Inner Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.itcse.materialdesignsearchviewlikegoogleplay"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
// Add the code for repositories here
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
        maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
// Add the dependencies here
    compile 'com.quinny898.library.persistentsearch:library:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'

}
```

Hope this help others in future.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
repositories {
   maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
```

You can find the repository here
https://oss.sonatype.org/#nexus-search;quick~dirchooser

Answer (score 1):

After trying the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22177318/270155) by Gabriele and a bit more digging, this worked for me

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.2-SNAPSHOT@aar'
}
```