# Import remote library from Maven

Tags: android, maven, gradle

I'm trying to add both Showcaseview by amlcurran and Android-DirectoryChooser by passy to my android app from MavenCentral, but I keep getting this error for both libraries:

```
Error:net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.0
```

This is my Project Gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

This is the inner one:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.2.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'org.jaudiotagger:jaudiotagger:2.0.1@jar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.0@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please provide the full error message and explain precisely which action is triggering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are not specifying the repository URL. Check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23879736/570612

Comment: The answer is correct but if anyone is confused as to where to add the code, see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30637170/1979347