# Android Studio could not resolve all dependencies (library is not found)

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just started to use Android Studio a few days ago and i've finally started to get it a bit. The only problem I still have is importing a library. I created a completely new test project and I'm trying to add a library to it. I'm not sure if this matters, but I am trying to add [Android-DirectoryChooser](https://github.com/passy/Android-DirectoryChooser).

1. First, I've chosen **Import module** and imported the library project that I've downloaded from GitHub
2. I then opened the build.gradle found inside my project and added the "compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.1@aar'"

This is how my build.gradle dependencies look like now:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.1@aar'
}
```

Then when I click "sync now" I get an error that says:

> Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':testproject'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testproject:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.1.
>        Required by:
>            TestProject:testproject:unspecified

Could someone let me knwow what I'm doing wrong or help me go through the steps of adding a library project to android studio and using it?

I tried searching for many tutorials on how to add library projects but they are all for older versions of Android Studio and nothing works for me.

Comment: Use the AAR from the repository. Check my answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/23879736/570612

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where the `compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:2.1@aar'` dependency came from. The error message states that it can't find it. There's no AAR version of that library at all on Maven Central, and neither is there a 2.1 version. If you've been able to successfully add a module for the library via the **Import module** command, then you can add a dependency to the module via Project Structure > Dependencies > + button > Module dependency